# calling a page with ajax based on url parameter

Tags: ajax

please can anyone help me with this problem that i've encountered. i'm able to capture a url parameter with javascript and i want to add it to my jquery code which calls a page in a div  but i'm able to do it. here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function urlink()
   {
      var tlink = window.location.search.substring(1);
   }

   jQuery(function($){
      $('#mydiv').load('real_news.asp?'+ urllink());
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Your function does not _return_ anything, so trying to concatenate its return value (most likely just _undefined_) with something else is rather pointless.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function urlink()
   {
      return window.location.search.substring(1);
   }

   jQuery(function($){
      $('#mydiv').load('real_news.asp?'+ urllink());
   });
</script>
```

Comment: now i'm able to pass the parameter. but the problem is the page doesn't load the page unless i refresh, any idea about how to make it work.